# Calling PHP object file results in the page not loading anymore

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

So I've been writing code for a project of mine where I have to create a sign up and login system for a website, and I'm pretty stuck right now.  I call the following "UserLogin.php" file:

```
class UserLogin
{
    private $username;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $userid;
    private $emailaddr;
    private $error;
    private $db;
    private $hash;
    private $salt;
    private $password

    public function __construct($user, $pass)
    {
        $this['username'] = $user;
        $this['password'] = $pass;
    }

    function getError()
    {
        return $this->error;
    }



    public function userLogin($username, $password)
    {
        if (checkUser($username)) {
            if (checkPass($password)) {
                $_SESSION['memberName'] = $this['username'];
                $_SESSION['fName'] = $this['firstName'];
                $_SESSION['lName'] = $this['lastName'];

                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $error = "Invalid username/password";
        }

    }



    public function checkUser($username)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('hostip', 'username', 'password', 'dbname', 3306);
        $stmt = prepare($mysqli);

        bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
        execute($stmt);
        bind_result($stmt, $this['user_id'], $this['username'], $this['salt'], $this['hash']);

        if (isset(fetch($stmt))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



     public function checkPass($password)
     {
         return hash_equals($this['hash'], crypt($password, $this['hash']));
         //return (hash_hmac("sha256", $password, $this['salt']) ===  $this['hash']);
     }
```

from another file, after the user has entered their username and password and then hit enter:

```
 include 'UserLogin.php';
 $username = $_GET["username"];
 $password = $_GET["pwd"];
 $usersession = new UserLogin($username, $password);
 echo "created";

 $var = $usersession->userLogin($username, $password);
 if ($var){
    echo "Verified";
 }
```

Thus far, I have not been able to find any errors but my website does not finish loading after the login button is hit.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also note I censored my actual database info in the mysqli variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your semicolon after `private $password`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolons (after `$password`), `isset()` can't to be called on a function and you can't use the class as an array `$this['username']`, you have to call it like `$this->username`.
Also your `userLogin()` method returns true if all ok but does nothing if user/pass are wrong.

The only **real advice** is to look at the error log and solve them one by one.